# Stacktrace for crash not understood

Tags: ios, crash, stack-trace

Can anyone explain me what the stacktrace below means?
What happens is that a background thread calls a method on the UIThread with

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     [self setupLaufbandBottom];

 });
```

The stacktrace on line 8 is where it gets called, that is how far I understand it.
But what is system doing in lines 1 - 7? And why would it have crashed? And what is strange to me is that there is no reference to any code from the app, it's all system stuff.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the code in Xcode with an exception breakpoint enabled?

Comment: Well I cant. It's a user crash and I receive the stacktrace from Crittercism.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it crashed when a `CAAnimation` was hitting it's `dealloc`, so when it was being released. (Line 2).

Line 4 is releasing a `CoreFoundation` object somewhere.

Without anymore information, my first guess would be something you're doing with Quartz was overreleased. To debug, I would use Instruments with the memory leak template and run through the app where ever you're doing any drawing or animating with Quartz.

Comment: Are you doing any animating anywhere? It could be from a third party library you're using, because the stack trace is calling out to `QuartzCore` which is Quartz

Comment: I add and remove annotations on a map. I also allow users to drag pins on a map. Otherwise, no third party libraries for drawing

Comment: My guess would be the crash is related to your code that processes dragging pins or changing annotations, because the crash is happening during some sort of animation. My only other suggestion is to beat the crap out of your app with an exception breakpoint set and see if you can recreate the issue

Answer (score 0):

In the crash log,

```
5 QuartzCore 0x... _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv
```

The line means you are using CALayer animation completion block, delegate, or something like that. UIView animation perhaps. For example, CABasicAnimation and animationDidStop:finished:. But the delegate object had been already released when the animation was finished I guess.